# Personalisation strings exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, email-studio

We are new to MC and would like to know if there is a way to query all the personalization strings that exists in all our contents. We are still using classic content but looking to move to Content Builder in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the MC club Vavan.

First off, I could certainly encourage you to move to Content Builder asap - not only for the better features, but Classic Builder will no longer be supported in Jan 2019.

When you are looking to 'query' the personalisation strings that existing in all our contents - could you please give some more explanation to specially what you are wanting to do.

SQL Queries can be used to query personalisation strings, but you could also use AMPScript within your email to 'query' a personalisation string.

Having a use case will help us understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @iMange thank you for your reply.

Yes we are "pushing" for the users to move to content builder as soon as possible.

The contents used are numerous. There are also quite a number of personalisations in each of them. The users would like to know the specific personalisations that exist in each content. Ie. Which contents contain the personalisation string date..is it possible to find this information out?

I am not familiar with Amscript but would like to learn.

Thank you